# What should be the correct grammar of Numpy broadcast multiplication

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I need to calculate the Dataframe `df` in batches, with a total of more than 10 million rows, as follows:

```
    ts_code trade_date   open   high    low  close  pre_close  change  pct_chg        vol       amount  adj_factor
0  000001.SZ   20210602  23.89  23.92  23.38  23.89      23.92   -0.03  -0.1254  497527.02  1176608.126     111.921
1  000002.SZ   20210602  26.50  27.18  26.31  26.76      26.60    0.16   0.6015  853545.06  2287264.276     153.901
2  000004.SZ   20210602  16.21  17.18  15.92  16.57      15.98    0.59   3.6921   47125.57    77192.135       4.064
3  000005.SZ   20210602   1.80   1.83   1.77   1.80       1.79    0.01   0.5587   82388.69    14812.102       9.268
4  000006.SZ   20210602   5.29   5.29   5.22   5.24       5.28   -0.04  -0.7576   58093.43    30539.090      36.507
5  000007.SZ   20210602   3.70   3.71   3.64   3.66       3.70   -0.04  -1.0811   29560.28    10841.980       8.284
6  000008.SZ   20210602   2.27   2.29   2.27   2.28       2.28    0.00   0.0000  126807.00    28933.202      22.408
7  000009.SZ   20210602  10.00  10.09   9.89   9.92      10.05   -0.13  -1.2935  253313.77   252740.741       8.881
8  000010.SZ   20210602   4.01   4.05   4.00   4.02       4.03   -0.01  -0.2481   45925.00    18472.845      10.775
9  000011.SZ   20210602  12.86  12.90  12.42  12.52      12.97   -0.45  -3.4695   91615.92   115647.098       3.875
```

When I use the following statement, I get an error

```
df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']] = df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].to_numpy() * df['adj_factor'].to_numpy()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-21-f7878ae9f133>", line 1, in <module>
    df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']] = df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].to_numpy() * df['adj_factor'].to_numpy()
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11516015,4) (11516015,)
```

What should be the correct grammar?

Comment: try: `df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].values[:,None] * df['adj_factor'].values[:,None]`

Comment: it takes `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.77 PiB for an array with shape (11516015, 11516015, 4) and data type float64`

Comment: Why don't multiply in place, e.g. `df['close'] = df['close'] * df['adj_factor']` and so on?

Comment: @crayxt That works, but I want to do the multiplication in one go. And `Numpy ` multiplication is faster than `Series`

Comment: Anurag got the shape adjustment wrong. I believe `df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']] = df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].to_numpy() * df[['adj_factor']].to_numpy()` should work, though I haven't checked. (Note the extra brackets in `df[['adj_factor']]`, indexing `df` with a 1-element list instead of a string.)

Comment: between you can also do `df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']]=df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].mul(df['adj_factor'],axis=0)`

Comment: try `df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']]=df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].values[:,None].reshape(10,4)*df['adj_factor'].values[:,None]
`

Comment: @Anurag Dabas That works. Is there a `numpy` multiplication method?

Comment: Maybe simpler: `df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].values * df['adj_factor'].values[:,None]`.

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica I used this method and got `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11516015,4) (11516015,) `

Comment: @Anurag Dabas My dataframe has 11516015 rows

Comment: @jaried: Did you put the extra brackets in?

Comment: @Cainã Max Couto-Silva I got `MemoryError: Unable to allocate 3.77 PiB for an array with shape (11516015, 11516015, 4) and data type float64`

Comment: that was for your sample dataframe that you posted

Comment: @ user2357112 supports Monica  Sorry, I didn’t pay attention, but this method is slower than `pd.mul`. `pd.mul`:`855 ms ± 3.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`,your method:`8.91 s ± 66.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)`

Comment: @Anurag Dabas Your method is fast, and the method of my post got error.

Comment: @Cainã Max Couto-Silva Thanks for the answer, I think `pd.mul()` is fast and simple enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `reshape()` as mention in comment by [`@user2357112 supports Monica`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica):

```
df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']]=df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].values*df['adj_factor'].values[:,None].reshape(11516015,1)
```

**OR**

Via `mul()` method

```
df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']]=df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].mul(df['adj_factor'],axis=0)
```

Comment: The `[:,None]` shape adjustment gets overridden by the subsequent `reshape`, and none of the shape adjustment should be necessary for the first operand of the multiplication.

Comment: yes Sir you are right I also think this but when I do this in sample dataframe provided by OP `(df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].values[:,None]).shape` it returns me a `3D` array of shape `(10,1,4)` so to make this 2D I used reshape method In the first opearand

Comment: The `reshape` on that one just undoes the effects of the `[:,None]`.

Comment: Yes sir but then you can't assign the result back to `df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']]` because the result is 3D array and dataframe is 2D structure...Sorry sir If I was wrong !!

Comment: Take out the `reshape` *and* the `[:,None]`.

Comment: `pd.mul()` is ten times faster than the first method

Comment: then use `df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].mul(df['adj_factor'],axis=0)` if it is faster **:)**

Answer (score 1):

In one way or other all of this has been covered in the comments and answers, but it might be worth adding some explanations.

```
df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']].to_numpy() * df['adj_factor'].to_numpy()
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (11516015,4) (11516015,)
```

A dataframe is 2d, that is `df.to_numpy()` will produce a 2d numpy array.  Index with a list of columns also returns a dataframe.

```
df[['close', 'open', 'high', 'low']]
```

With 4 columns, its `to_numpy()` is `(11516015,4)`.

But selecting one column returns a `Series`, with a 1d shape.  This is the `to_numpy` that is `(11516015,)` shaped.

The 2 key rules of numpy broadcasting are:

- try to match dimensions by adding leading dimensions
- adjust all size 1 dimensions to match

A (n,4) array can multiply as (4,), because the later expands to (1,4) and on to (n,4).  But a (n,) can only be expanded to (1,n).

So the solution is to change `df['adj_factor'].to_numpy()` to `(11516015,1)`.

```
df['adj_factor'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1)  # add trailing dimension
df['adj_factor'].to_numpy()[:,None]
df[['adj_factor']]           # list indexing
```

Comment: I understand, but why `pd.mul()` is ten times faster than `numpy` direct multiplication?

Comment: With a small test array, `df[['adj_factor']]` is much slower than `df['adj_factor']`.  Compared to extracting a Series, or `to_numpy()`, making a new data frame is surprisingly expensive.  I haven't use `mul`, so can't say much about what it's doing, except that with keeping track of indices and such, it has a lot more to do than plain array multiplication.